# Server 2012 DNS keeps adding a forwarder on it's own

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm having a weird problem that must be something simple I'm overlooking.

Deployed a new Server 2012 PDC to replace a SBS2011 DC.  I had it inherit the DNS before decommissioning the old one.  Single server environment, same box handles DNS.

Somehow our gateway router IP address was in the list of DNS forwarders, creating a loop that floods/disables our internal LAN until either DNS or the router is restarted (and then it only last 3-4 minutes before killing the connection again).

Anyway, I've removed that IP from the forwarders list several times but each morning when I come in it's back.

Is there a policy re-adding it overnight or might my DNS service implementation be flaky?  The DNS mmc console has frozen a few times trying to edit the forwarders list so I'm suspicious.

Comment: `I had it inherit the DNS before decommissioning the old one` - How does one go about having a Windows DNS server inherit DNS? I've never heard of that before. `Somehow our gateway router IP address was in the list of DNS forwarders, creating a loop` - How so? Does the router have the server set as it's DNS server? `Is there a policy re-adding it overnight` - There's no policy that I'm aware of that can do such a thing. Does anyone else have administrator level access to the server?

Comment: I may not have worded the "inherit DNS" sentence right.  DNS replicated from the old server to the new one before being demoted/decommissioned.  This forwarder entry existedin the previous server but wasn't a problem.  The router is set to use the new server as DNS and this forwarder entry on the server uses the router DNS when it can't resolve internally.  Watching the traffic all it takes is one request that it can't resolve and then they ping-pong back and forth until connectivity dies (takes maybe a minute).    Anyway all I'm trying to figure out is how 192.168.1.1 keeps getting added

Comment: OK, then does the router have the server set as it's DNS server? If not then I'm not seeing how a `loop` is being created. How did you determine that their was a loop? What are the symptoms? Did you run a packet capture on the server and see DNS requests for external resources being forwarded back and forth between the server and the router?

Comment: Determined by watching the traffic.  All I know is that removing 192.168.1.1 from the DNS forwarders list on the Server solves the problem and that each of the past 3 mornings 192.168.1.1 is back in the list!  Just trying to figure out how THAT is happening.

Comment: Can you try searching the registry for "AddedDnsForwarder"

Comment: Nothing in the registry matching that.  Since I originally posted I left the DNS mmc console open on the server and when I just went to search the registry the damned router IP IS BACK IN THE LIST!  Could the router be adding itself?

Comment: Wait there is an "AddedDnsForwarder" registry key pointing to 192.168.1.1!  It didn't come up when I searched for the text, only when I searched for the IP.

Comment: It might be just a red herring, but at least you have something to investigate. The issue is probably related to the fact that SBS adds default gateway to the DNS forwarders list (supposedly, I've never had my hands on SBS)

Comment: Dammit the router is back in the list of DNS Forwarders this morning even after I deleted that key yesterday!  My head is going to explode.

Comment: OK, I renamed that key yesterday trying to disable it. Something recreated it overnight.  I still have the renamed key and now a brand new "AddedDnsForwarder" key pointing to 192.168.1.1 in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Server\Networking\

Comment: Don't give up. Is your current server Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard?

Comment: Server 2012 Essentials.

Comment: Oh, there was no mention of 'Essentials' in your question. Seems that behavior you describe is expected in Essentials. Why don't you just configure router to use 8.8.8.8 as dns? If not, try something like [this](http://titlerequired.com/2012/05/04/quick-fix-dns-forwarders-sbs-2011-essentials/)